What's the canonical way to get the list of possible languages supported by my i18next instance?
I'm using i18next/i18next-react in my React application. I have it configured as you'd expect with various languages at the root level:
i18n
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: "en",
    resources: {
      en: { ... },
      de: { ... },
      pl: { ... },
      // ...
    },
  });

The problem I'm running into is this: I want to get the list of languages my i18next instance is currently supporting. I want to know that so I can present a list of options for a language picker and know what I could call
i18next.changeLanguage() with.
While that would normally be the same ["en", "de", "pl"] list I provided to begin with, i18next supports modifying resources during runtime, so it might have changed since. I want to ask i18next directly what its current state is and use it for a source of truth.
My initial guess was that this might be supplied by i18next.languages but that instead relates to the languages currently active: in the above config, it would be ["en"] when I'm using English, and ["pl", "en"] when I'm in Polish, leaving out the fact that "de" is available in both cases.
I do currently seem to have this option, but it seems a bit like I'm doing something hacky that I shouldn't:
Object.keys(i18n.services.resourceStore.data)
// ["en", "de", "pl"] if the list wasn't modified since

// this definitely reflects changes, too:
i18n.addResourceBundle("ko", "translations", {});
Object.keys(i18n.services.resourceStore.data)
// ["en", "de", "pl", "ko"]

Is this the correct way to do it, or is there a better canonical way to do it?

This is my i18next config:
import i18n from 'i18next';
import {initReactI18next} from 'react-i18next';
import en from './lang/en.json';
import cn from './lang/cn.json';
import bh from './lang/bh.json';

const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: en,
  },
  cn: {
    translation: cn,
  },
  bh: {
    translation: bh,
  },
};

export type TSupportedLanguages = keyof typeof resources;
export const SupportedLanguages = Object.keys(
  resources,
) as (keyof typeof resources)[]; // I turn object keys to an array

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    compatibilityJSON: 'v3',
    resources,
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    lng: 'en',
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // react already safes from xss
    },
  });

export default i18n;

later i can use SupportedLanguages as an array of Supported Languages

